# In ARC, what happens to the memory of an object that is reinitialized?

Tags: ios, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

Let's say I have a method called test.

```
test{
    NSString *answer = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"VALUE 1"];
    answer = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"VALUE 2"];
}
```

When answer got reinitialized, what happens to the memory of the first initialization under ARC?

Comment: You have an extraneous `@` on the second line.

Comment: Note that NSString *answer = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"VALUE 1"]; is exactly the same as NSString *answer = @"VALUE 1";

Comment: It went to NSObject heaven.  If it was good it may be reincarnated as an NSNumber or a UIImage.

Comment: @Catfish_Man - Not exactly.  The first REQUIRES the creation of a new NSString object containing the bytes "VALUE 1".  The second simply uses the "interned" literal string.

Comment: @HotLicks, that's not actually required. In both cases you get a statically allocated string with current compiler/runtime.

Comment: In practice, in both cases, you should end up with the same pointer. In theory, yes, that's not guaranteed.

Comment: @Catfish_Man - Yeah, a test shows you're right -- they cheat!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first string is released (the string which was created in `[[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"VALUE 1"];`)

`answer` in this case is an object with *strong* ownership qualification. So from the [docs](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#ownership-qualification), this is what happens when you assign to `answer`:

> For __strong objects, the new pointee is first retained; second, the lvalue is loaded with primitive semantics; third, the new pointee is stored into the lvalue with primitive semantics; and finally, the old pointee is released. This is not performed atomically; external synchronization must be used to make this safe in the face of concurrent loads and stores.

Comment: Do you know which objects ARC handles and which it doesn't?

Comment: ARC manages Objective-C objects, including blocks. It does not manage CoreFoundation objects, or C++ objects, or any memory that you allocate yourself using [mc]alloc. Is that what you mean?